# Вставные конструкции? Как лучше?

Tags: пунктуация

> 1. Король дал мне имя — «Рихон», — которое выгравировал на тонкой цепи, повязанной вокруг моей шеи, и велел сковать мои руки браслетами.
> 2. Король дал мне имя — «Рихон», которое выгравировал на тонкой цепи, повязанной вокруг моей шеи, — и велел сковать мои руки браслетами.
> 3. Король дал мне имя — «Рихон», которое выгравировал на тонкой цепи, повязанной вокруг моей шеи, и велел сковать мои руки браслетами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Только один вариант оформлен правильно: Король дал мне имя — «Рихон», которое выгравировал на тонкой цепи, повязанной вокруг моей шеи, и велел сковать мои руки браслетами.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

Можно предложить три варианта оформления данного сообщения.

(1) Король дал мне имя Рихон, которое выгравировал на тонкой цепи, повязанной вокруг моей шеи, и велел сковать мои руки браслетами.

Нейтральный вариант, имя собственное и связанная с ним дополнительная информация никак не выделены.

(2) Король дал мне имя — Рихон, которое выгравировал на тонкой цепи, повязанной вокруг моей шеи, и велел сковать мои руки браслетами.

Обособление имени собственного  акцентирует на нем внимание, но дополнительная информация по-прежнему идет в основном сообщении. (Второе тире поглощается запятой).

(3) Король дал мне имя  Рихон - он  выгравировал его  на тонкой цепи, повязанной вокруг моей шеи, - и велел сковать мои руки браслетами.

С помощью тире дополнительная  информация выделена на второй план.
Обособление  с помощью тире части предложения   «Рихон, которое выгравировал на тонкой цепи, повязанной вокруг моей шеи»  невозможно, так как это не цельная конструкция -  слово «которое» согласовано со словом «имя».

Примечание. Использование кавычек должно быть как-то обосновано.

Answer (score 2):

Это не вставная конструкция, это приложение. Имя какое? Рихон. Если интонация нейтральна, без выделения имени как уточнения и имя не несёт никакой особенной эмоциональной нагрузки, то не оно не обособляется: Король дал мне имя Рихон,  которое выгравировал на тонкой цепи, повязанной вокруг моей шеи, и велел сковать мои руки браслетами.

Если имя означает что-то важное для смысла фразы,можно его взять в кавычки. Если есть оттенок уточнения, обособляем запятыми, тире возможно как интонационное (Король дал мне имя — «Рихон», которое выгравировал на тонкой цепи, повязанной вокруг моей шеи, и велел сковать мои руки браслетами), но нежелательно, потому что тире для выделения приложения ставится в конце предложения, а у Вас дальше идёт причастный оборот  именно к тому существительному, которое определяет приложение.В художественной литературе это авторский знак, он возможен, но как норма - нет.